# laravel unique validation on foreign key

Tags: laravel, validation

I have database table `streets` in which I am storing `name` and `block_id` as foreign key from the `blocks` table. So I want the name of `street` should be unique in every `block`. for example if the name of `street` is **street 1** with `block_id` 1, it should not be added again with `block_id` 1 but it should be allowed to add **street 1** with `block_id` 2 or 3. How can I get it with Laravel validation?

**My validation Code**:

here you can see I am validating uniqueness only on those records which have delete = false.

```
$validatedValues = $request->validate([
            'block' => 'required',
            'street' => [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('streets', 'sName')->where(function ($query) {
                    return $query->where('delete', false);
                })
            ],
            'street_width' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Comment: show some code so someone can help you to solve your issue

Comment: @JohnLobo check it now

Comment: i have posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this with street key in your code

```
'name' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('streets')->where(function ($query) use($request) {
        return $query->where('name', $request->name)
        ->where('block_id', $request->block_id);
    }),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

1. Create request -> PHP artisan make:request StreetsRequest
2. in ur controller find the store method or whatever the name u put for storing ur data, and change the (Request $request) to (StreetsRequest $request)

```
use App\Http\Requests\StreetsRequest;
....
public function store(StreetsRequest $request){
        $request->validated();

        // Do whatever u want after validate
}
```

3. Open your StreetsRequest file and inside the return [] put sth like this

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
...
'block_id' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('streets','block_id')->ignore(request('id')),
],
```

i hope it will work , let us know if u still have any problem, thx

check laravel validation for more
[https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation]

Comment: i does not want `block_id` to be unique. i want street name to be unique. if name is **street 1** for `block_id` 1 then **street 1** should not be allowed for `block_id` 1. **street 1** should be allowed for `block_id` 2,3....

Comment: Hi friend, have you tried the code ? if the street name are unique then u cant put another **street 1** with different `block_id` cuz the street name are unique that means u cant add another **street 1** on ur database....

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing custom validation for that

```
 $validator =  $request->validate([
                'block' => 'required',
                'street' => [

                    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use($request){
                      
                       $street= Street::where('delete', false)->where(function ($query)use($request){
                            $query->where('sName',$request->sName);
                            $query->where('block_id',$request->block_id );
                        })->exists();
                       if($street){
                           $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
                       }
                    },
                ],
            ]);
```

I hope for streets table you have Street model

if any issue let me know .